# Can't extract the text of an html tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, web-scraping

I am having trouble extracting content of an html tag through the chrome console. I think I am missing something pretty obvious but it's been half an hour I'm trying stuff and I can't make it work, so I'm asking help :)

I want to extract some code from that page: http://www.societe.com/societe/deezer-511716573.html

Here's the html snippet I'm interested in:

```
<table id="rensjur">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Dénomination</td>
     <td>DEEZER</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to extract the content "DEEZER" of the second < td >. I am using the following:

```
$("#rensjur tbody td:nth-child(2)").text();
```

but this raises an error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).text is not a function(…)`

However, when I call:

```
$("#rensjur tbody td:nth-child(2)")
```

It gives me the right HTML tag:

```
<td>DEEZER</td>
```

How can I get only "DEEZER" as a result ? What am I doing wrong with the `text()` method ?

Comment: The only reasonable answer will be you haven't imported the correct jquery code. Try redownloading again.

Comment: Which is odd, the basic `.text()` support has been here since version 1.0, and the extended one has been here since 1.4, i'm assuming his problem lies with executing this code before the body exists. could you try adding `$(document).ready(function() { });`

Comment: I tried reloading and it still doesn't work :(
I am executing the code in the chrome console, so I don't think it can come from a document.ready thing. And I am able to get the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `innerHTML` property; that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any error, it works

```js
console.log ( $("#myId tbody td:nth-child(2)").text() )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myId">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Hello</td>
     <td>world</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert($("#myId tbody td:nth-child(2)").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myId">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Hello</td>
     <td>world</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log ( $("#myId tbody td:nth-child(1)").innerHTML )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myId">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Hello</td>
     <td>world</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```